# quasar select use-input validation rule

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js, quasar

I am using a QSelect component from Quasar framework v1.9.2

it uses `use-input` and a filter function. I want to use some kind of validation for the input to indicate that the user has to type at least two characters.

But when using `rules` attribute the validation works on the current selection, not on the `use-input` field. How can i apply validation rules on the input field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this would helps
you can use binding error like that:

```
:error="attribute.length>2"
```